# c# remove object from list if ID value doesn't exist on web link

Tags: c#, json, list, object, compare

I have a function that takes all `Json` values from a `Api link` and deserializes all of them into an object list. I need to compare the `ID value` from that `object list` with [all ID values listed here](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings). However using the function i used [on the other Api link](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron) doesnt work as that returned `Json` structure, this one doesnt.

```
// parameters given are "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/" + "1"
var spidyApi_idByName = api_Handler.objFromApi_idToName(spidyApiUrl, startPage);
```

The function where above code calls to

```
public static RootObject objFromApi_idToName(string spidyApiUrl, int page)
        {
            RootObject rootObject = null;
            RootObject tempRootObject = null;

            do{
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(spidyApiUrl + "/" + page);

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()){
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    tempRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

                    if (rootObject == null){
                        rootObject = tempRootObject;
                    }
                    else{
                        rootObject.results.AddRange(tempRootObject.results);
                        rootObject.count += tempRootObject.count;
                    }
                }
                page++;
            }

            while (tempRootObject != null && tempRootObject.last_page != tempRootObject.page);
            return rootObject;
        }
```

How can I check if the ID values in spidyApi_idByName [exist here](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings) and if they don't be removed from the object list.

EDIT, more general info:

I have a textbox where you can enter your search. This is then send to a Api link to conver the text into ID's of the items that match the search.Example searching for iron will return [all these values](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron). However I need to check if these items are sellable which there are 2 ways of doing.

[I can access this link](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/), these are all ID's of itmes that are sellable and check if which item ID in the object list doesnt exist in above link.

Or take the Item ID that is in the object list and retrieve more information from a different Api link. This link includes a property called Flags, if this propertie has the value "NoSell" it should be removed from the object list. [Example link](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/45053), this item has the property Flags with value NoSell

Short: translate text into item ID, check if this ID is sellable.

Comment: Specify more details what are you trying to do in general, without implementation details. Like "how do i compare two collection with some rule" or "how can i exclude items from one collection based on other".

Comment: @Yura I have edited my question with a more detailed description of what i am asking and trying to achieve. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you obtain a list of ids from your https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings link:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
    HttpWebRequest request =
                    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings");
                try
                {
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            ids = reader.ReadToEnd().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim())
                                .ToList();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
return ids;
```

This is not a JSON, it's a comma separated string. So you need to parse it in order to obtain the list of id's.

Comment: I see how this wouldw ork but how do i return this value to the function call? I have tried to define ids outside the try but the `local variables must be initialized`

Comment: I have the error on return that i can not convert string to rootObject, this is probably due to the fact that the function returns the Rootobject. But i dont know what i should write in the function as return. `public static RootObject objFromApi_idExistListings(string gw2ApiUrl)`

Comment: You can return `List<string>`